# iOS Swift Rotation Animation Not Staying Put

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am playing around with rotating an UIImageView.  The rotation animation works fine but at the end of if the image goes back to its original orientation.  Below is an extension I use to rotate it:

```
extension UIView {
func rotate(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, degrees:Double, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    let radians = CGFloat(degrees * M_PI / degrees)
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(radians)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration

    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }
    self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

}

I have auto-layout turned off.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In straight Core Animation you have to actually set the property you're animating. Animating alone just shows the effect and then pops back to the starting value. While setting the `fillMode` and `removedOnCompletion` will *work visually*, the actual value of the rotation property on the layer remains the original value, not the ending value you specified in the `toValue` property for your **animation**. The end result is **only visual**.

I would suggest you either use the `UIView` animation functions as Jan suggested or, you can explicitly set the property in your animation--something like:

```
func rotate(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, degrees:Double, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    let radians = CGFloat(degrees * M_PI / degrees)
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(radians)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration

    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }
    self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)

    // Actually set the layer's property
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These properties should help:

```
rotateAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
rotateAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use animateWithDuration to animate your view.

```
func rotate(duration: NSTimeInterval, degrees: CGFloat, completionDelegate: (finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    let radians = CGFloat(degrees * CGFloat(M_PI) / degrees)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians)
    }, completion: completionDelegate)
}
```